# How to create a coroutine Dispatcher for the current thread?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to create a `Dispatcher` for the current thread? Check this sample code as an example of what I want to accomplish:

```kotlin
val dispatcher = if (parallel) {
  Dispatcher.Default
} else {
  // What should I write here so I just use the current thread to run doStuff?
}

val deferredList = list.map {
  async(dispatcher) { doStuff(it) }
}
```

Comment: You probably actively can't.  You could use the current _Dispatcher_, but that's different from the current thread.

Comment: `runBlocking` is the one that uses the current thread for its internal dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a coroutine, you're passing a `CoroutineContext` as argument. If you don't pass anything, the new coroutine is built with the current `CoroutineContext` (its parent's context).

Instead of a `Dispatcher` you should aim to a `CoroutineContext`:

```
val context = if (parallel) {
    Dispatchers.Default
} else {
    coroutineContext
}

val deferredList = list.map {
    async(context) { doStuff(it) }
}
```

You can also "extract" every `Element` of the context individually using the `Element` type as key:

**Job:** `coroutineContext[Job]`

**Dispatcher:** `coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]`

**ExceptionHandler:** `coroutineContext[CoroutineExceptionHandler]`

**Name:** `coroutineContext[CoroutineName]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dispatchers.Unconfined](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html), it's used exactly to run on a current thread.

The whole code will look as follows:

```
val dispatcher = if (parallel) Dispatcher.Default else Dispatchers.Unconfined

val deferredList = list.map {
  async(dispatcher) { doStuff(it) }
}
```

Comment: Extracted from the documentation: "[...] and lets the coroutine resume in *whatever thread that is used by the corresponding suspending function*." (The enphasis is mine). It starts in the correct thread but then it could jump to any thread.